# ReactJS event.preventDefault(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to submit a form data, and my main requirement is that the entire page should not reload on the form submission. Hence i tried adding event.preventDefault(); in my form submit function, but it is giving me an error.

I tried various solutions mentioned in various other stackoverflow answers, but none of them worked.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        rating:5,
        review:"",
        user:""
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

async handleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    //console.log(name);
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value})
    //console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleSubmit(event,type,id) {
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    alert(event);
    console.log("event",event);
    event.preventDefault();
    data.append("type",type)
    fetch('http://localhost:10000/movie/addreview/'+id, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
  }
```

Below is my form

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(this,type,id)} target="#">
                <div className="ratingfield">
                    <h1 className="ratingtext">Enter Username </h1> 
                    <input name="user"  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.user} className="input" size="10"></input> 
                     </div>

                     <br/>
                <br/>
                <div className="ratingfield">
                    <h1 className="ratingtext">Enter Rating from 1-10</h1> 
                    <input name="rating"  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.rating} className="input" size="4"></input> 
                     </div>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <center><h1 className="new"> Enter Review</h1></center>
                <center><textarea name="review" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} className="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></center>
                <center><input type="submit" className="sbtbtn"></input></center>
  </form>
```

Any solutions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read more about event handlers [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

You are calling the handler during the render stage rather than as a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) passed to the event and since your handler doesn't return anything then the event won't receive anything.

Try this

```
handleSubmit(type, id, event){
  // insert your logic here
}

render() {
  return ( 
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this,type,id)} target="#">
       /* JSX goes here */
     </form>
)}
```

The bind function binds arguments and scope to your callback ( the handler `handleSubmit`).

The arguments you pass to the `bind` function will come before the arguments that will be passed to your handler by React internally

the `this` is referring to the function's scope once it's called. This allows your to call `this.setState` because `this` is bound by the component class

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `this` object to the function not the `event`. You have to pass `event`:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmit(event, type, id) } target="#">
```

**OR:** Using `.bind()`

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit.bind(this, type, id) } target="#">
```

Comment: Are you sure ```event``` is the parameter to be passed ? i tried passing ```this```, but didn't work

Comment: adding ```event``` throws the following error ```Unexpected use of 'event'```